# How to put custom icon on polygon?

Tags: javascript, style, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

This is my code to draw a polygon on map but instead on putting a circle on each point, I want to put a image (custom icon). How do I do that?

```
var draw = new MapboxDraw({//modifier des buttons pour dessiner
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        line_string: true,
        polygon:true,
        trash: true,
    },
    userProperties: true,
      styles: [
          {
          "id": "gl-draw-polygon-stroke-active",//change le style de ligne de polygon
          "type": "line",

          "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round"
          },
          "paint": {
            "line-color": "#D20C0C",
            "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
            "line-width": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active",//change le style des points dd polygon
          "type": "circle",
          "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
          "paint": {
            "circle-radius": 5,
            "circle-color": "#3c33ff",
          }
        }
       ]
    });
```